# redim nested array

Tags: arrays, ms-access, multidimensional-array, vba

i have an array path... this array contains a list of nested array paths. it could look something like this:

```
path( 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 )
"1" | 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 |
"2" | 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 |
"3" | 1, 1,  , 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2 |
"Val" A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I
```

now i have a small loop to get the maximum of the second row.

```
x = 1
For c = 0 To UBound(path)
   If IsArray(path(c)) Then
        If CInt(path(c)(x)) <= maxDimension1 Then
        maxDimension1 = CInt(path(c)(x))
        End If
    End If
Next
redim preserve pathValues(maxDimension1 - 1)
```

i must now find the maximum number of elements for the elements in row "2" and redim the array-Element in pathValues to this.
i tried:

```
For Dimension2 = 1 To maxDimension1
    For c = 0 To UBound(Path)
        If IsArray(Path(c)) Then
            If CInt(Path(c)(x)) = Dimension2 Then
                If CInt(Path(c)(2)) >= maxDimension2 Then
                maxDimension2 = CInt(Path(c)(2))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    redim PathValues(c)(maxDimension2) //Syntax Error
    next
next
```

is there a way to avoid a workaround with multidimensional array?
for explanation: the pathValues would look like this in the end:

```
PathValues() = (C,(E, I),(B, F, H),(A, D, G))
```

Comment: is it necessary to be so complicated, what are you trying to solve? Also you cannot redim the last dimension of an array.

Comment: @Philip A Barnes: yes unfortunately it is necessary to be so complicated, but it would be new to me that i could not redim an array
this is the solution to create test-data for a SNMP-Simulation from Data in a Database to check error-handling

Comment: Actually, you can `Redim` the last dimension of an array, or any dimension if not using `Preserve`.  If you use the `Preserve` keyword, as in `Redim Preserve` you can only Redim the last dimension.

Comment: For your syntax error, try `redim PathValues(c, maxDimension2)`.

Comment: @Doug Glancy: and also this is a redim for a multidimensional array, which is not present in this moment.still i want to work around the use of multidimensional arrays for the sake of saving space and differentiating in between empty values and empty elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by recursively calling a function that uses x as "depth" and the full path to create one single array containing empty elements for the values that get written in later.
one just needs to add a statement sorting out the upper bounds you do not want because they belong to other arrays. for all else it works fine

```
Function iterate_Path(path As Variant, x As Integer, value_x As Variant) As Variant
Dim insideArray, returnPath
returnPath = Array()

For c = 0 To UBound(path)
    If IsArray(path(c)) Then
       If CInt(path(c)(x)) = value_x Then
            If x <> UBound(path(c)) Then
                If CInt(path(c)(x)) > UBound(returnPath) + 1 Then
                    ReDim Preserve returnPath(CInt(path(c)(x)) - 1)
                End If
                returnPath(path(c)(x) - 1) = iterate_Path(path, x + 1, path(c)(x))
            ElseIf CInt(path(c)(x)) > UBound(returnPath) + 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve returnPath(CInt(path(c)(x)) - 1)
            End If
       ElseIf CInt(path(c)(x)) > UBound(returnPath) + 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve returnPath(CInt(path(c)(x)) - 1)
            If x + 1 = UBound(path(c)) Then
            returnPath(CInt(path(c)(x)) - 1) = iterate_Path(path, x + 1, path(c)(x))
            End If
       ElseIf x + 1 = UBound(path(c)) Then
            If CInt(path(c)(x)) > UBound(returnPath) + 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve returnPath(CInt(path(c)(x)) - 1)
            End If
            returnPath(CInt(path(c)(x)) - 1) = iterate_Path(path, x + 1, path(c)(x))
       End If
    Else
        returnPath(CInt(path(c)(x)) - 1) = Empty
    End If
Next
iterate_Path = returnPath
End Function
```